# Mark of the Ninja time freeze bug

Tags: mark-of-the-ninja

I've encountered a bug in Mark of the Ninja, where when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> it's supposed to stop time, and give you objects to hit or points to grapple while in mid-air.

In my case, however, it just makes objects targetable, and it doesn't stop time or let me hover in mid-air to perform dagger tricks.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation?

Comment: Which costume are you wearing? some of them remove your ability to stop time.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the Path Of Might or Path Of Wisdom costume, Focus does not stop time. Could be because of that.

Source: http://markoftheninja.wikia.com/wiki/Costumes

Answer (score 3):

Both the Path of Wisdom and Path of Might costumes prevent your Focus from stopping time.